# Keep selection while switching through edit and object mode?

Tags: mesh, objects, selection-tools

I wonder if and how the above questioned action can be done. Because for me now it would be a lot easier just to pick the desired mesh in object mode, switch to edit mode while still having it selected. 
Would be awesome if someone could help with an answer. :)
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: In my experience, if I'm working on something in edit mode, and have one or more blender elements selected, and then switch to object mode, select another object, go to edit mode, and work on that object in edit mode, then go back to the first object, switching to edit mode, the elements that I had selected when I left, are still selected when I return. So I'm not real clear what your asking. Please, might you give more specific details?

Comment: I mean the mesh I have selected in object mode would still be selected in edit mode to work on with it if needed.

Comment: again in my experience, the mesh selected in object mode *is* still selected in edit mode, otherwise you would not be able to edit the mesh.

Comment: Sorry for long time not responding, I wasn't online last time. So, to light up the mistery of my strange thinking: Yes, you are right, the selection is kept when changing to edit mode, so you can edit this specific mesh, my thought was more to already have all faces/edges/vertices already selected without having to select them with B tool, or by hand.